# How to launch an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController of only contacts that have mobile numbers?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

Apple provided a sample project called PeoplePicker that launches an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` of only contacts that have email addresses:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

// The people picker will only display the person's name, image and email properties in ABPersonViewController.
picker.displayedProperties = @[@(kABPersonEmailProperty)];

// The people picker will enable selection of persons that have at least one email address.
picker.predicateForEnablingPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emailAddresses.@count > 0"];
```

How do I display only the contacts that have mobile/telephone numbers? I already dug around the Apple docs to find what key to use for the `@count` operation (`emailAddresses` in this example), but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ABPersonPhoneNumbersProperty` like so:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.@count > 0", ABPersonPhoneNumbersProperty];
```

Comment: This, and "phoneNumbers" worked--because that's the value of `ABPersonPhoneNumbersProperty`. Thanks!